# How automatically check for erros in the code (PHP, Python, HTML, Javascript) in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, python, plugins, package, sublimetext2

How can I automatically check errors in my code when I'm using `Sublime Text 2`? Or,is there `Sublime Text 2` packages/plugins to check if the code have errors?

My main languages is Python, PHP, Javascript, HTML, so, I mainly searching for things that can help with them.

--
Examples to understood the tool needed:

```
<?php
    echa 'test'
?>
```

The tool shold return (or with something similar) that there isn't `echa` method and the colon(`;`) is missing.

```
<html>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</.html>
```

The tool should return (or with something similar) that the `HTML` tag was not closed and there's no tag named `.html`.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function(){
        document.writ('Test');
    }
</script>
```

The tool should return (or with something similar) that there isn't `writ` method.

This simples examples is just to explain a bit more.

Comment: The text editors will help with errors via text highlighting, but I'm not aware of any that will evaluate your code. Also, please work on your  accept rating so people will be more inclined to help you.

Comment: 2 are over a few months old. Work on those, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mainly use sublime2 for Python programming and SublimeLinter is awesome for that, finds unused imports/variables and makes you follow the PEP8

Apparently it support PHP aswell :)

https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeLinter

Here is also a plugin for some nice python autocompletion https://github.com/JulianEberius/SublimeRope

Comment: Very interesting. I will take a look and return Daniel.